# SQL - Sum two rows of data while still showing the rest of the rows

Tags: sql, sum, row

As an example, there is a table that has Sales Reps and their sales listed in a table. Two of the rep ID's are for the same Rep, so I need to be able to combine these two rows into one in a query while still displaying the rest of the rows. Whether this is done in the SQL query, or in PHP either way would work.

So here is what the table would look like:

```
ID    Sales
100   $5
101   $10
102   $2
500   $3
```

I need it to output like this:

```
ID    Sales
100   $8
101   $10
102   $2
```

Where ID 100's sales is a sum of both 100 and 500.

I'm sure this can't be too hard, but I'm not that familiar with SQL or PHP yet, trying to learn though. Thank you.

Comment: What field can be used to determine that 100 and 500 is the same person? (Why does he have two entries?) How do you determine that the result should have the id 100, and not 500?

Comment: Is there another table which says which Rep IDs belong to the same Rep? Or are you going to manually refer to them everytime you want to perform this?

Comment: I'm going to have to manually refer to the two id's belonging to each other everytime I need this. I am working off of a read-only database. The reason they have two entries is a long story and can't be avoided due to the way the system we use is setup. I'm going to have to manually make the ID 100 when combined. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two separate query then union

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Sales) FROM table WHERE ID IN (100,500)
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Sales FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (100,500)
```

Comment: That should do it! Knew it shouldn't be that hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select id, sum(sales) from your_table 
group by case id 
         when 100 then -1 
         when 500 then -1 
         else id end;
```

Comment: How would this work? Not sure what the -1 does. I get that case is an if else statement and this way looks promising, I'd just like to know what is happening in this query with the -1 part. Thanks!

Comment: That actually works in 1 select statement. See this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8de1f/2).It makes an exception for id 100 and 500 and adds them. The query tells sql to treat id 500 and id 100 as they where the same id: -1.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Now i just got to figure out how to integrate this to my already overly complicated query...